# What would be the appropriate patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Recently i faced an interview.I answered some questions well.For some questions,without knowing answer also,i answered as if i were aware of the answer.one of such question is to find out the matching pattern of the following.

Don't laugh at my answers.Just i tried my level best at interview.

---

```
  Item                      Pattern
```

---

```
1) Iterator                  Behavior

2) Event                     Publisher/Subscriber

3) Delegate                  Callback 

4) Callback                 Function chaining

5) Garbage Collection       B-Tree

6) Threading               Producer-Consumer

7) String                  builder

8) StringBuilder           builder

9) Expression Tree         builder

10) Lambda                  callback

11) Webservice              Service Oriented Architecture

12) Stack                   LIFO /Datastructure  

13) Queue                   FIFIO/Datastructure

14) Regular Expression      Wild card mapping pattern

15) WCF                     SOA/Communication Pattern

16) foreach                 behavior
```

I really thing some of the items do not related to pattern.What would be your answer,suppose you face such  questions?

Comment: Did you have a finite list of pattern names to work with or were you suppose to just randomly guess?  Some items are weird.  For example, why is iterator listed?  Iterator is itself a pattern.

Comment: lot of itemes were asked to identify the pattern.May be they would have tested me where i will tell these are not associated with pattern(To test my knowledge).I did not type anythig what i think,these are few asked at interview.May be the order is random.

Comment: @Brain Gideon Iterator itself is a pattern i agree. But we can give other name too "The iterator pattern is an example of a behavioral pattern" -This quote is taken from Jon Skeet's C# in Depth.

Comment: Behavioral is NOT another name for the Iterator pattern. The Iterator pattern is a specific type of a behavioral pattern. "Behavioral" is the family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my choices:

1. Iterator
2. Observer
3. Delegate
4. Visitor
5. Strategy
6. Thread Pooling, Monitor, Lock...there are entire books on Concurrency Patterns
7. I would not use a pattern
8. Perhaps a Composite.
9. Interpreter
10. Command pattern, perhaps
11. This would involve architectural patterns, and probably a number of them.
12. I would not use a pattern
13. I would not use a pattern
14. Interpreter
15. I don't know what you mean by this? Windows Communication Foundation?
16. Iterator

I'll try to elaborate after work.